# Get index of array of objects via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, utility

I have the following array:

```
var = array[
            {"id" : "aa", "description" : "some description"},
            {"id" : "bb", "description" : "some more description"},
            {"id" : "cc", "description" : "a lot of description"}]
```

and I try to find the index of the array that contains the `id === "bb"`. The solution I came up with is the following:

```
var i = 0;
while(array[i].id != "bb"){
   i++;
}
alert(i) //returns 1
```

Is there an easier way that has cross-browser functionality? I tried `$.inArray(id,array)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Easier? What part of that isn't already easy? (though you should add some validation to make sure the id exists)

Comment: I know I just think I have to avoid loops as much as possible ;) So I thought maybe there's a way....
Good point with the validation. A simple try/catch should do the job, right?

Comment: No need for try/catch. Just use a `for` loop instead of `while` and use `-1` as the result if none is found - that seems to be common. I'll do you an answer I think

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problem with the complexity of your code, but I would recommend a couple of changes including adding some validation in case the value does not exists. Further more you can wrap it all in a reusable helper function...

```
function getArrayIndexForKey(arr, key, val){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i][key] == val)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This can then be used in your example like so:

```
var index = getArrayIndexForKey(array, "id", "bb");
//index will be -1 if the "bb" is not found
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6LsVn/)

NOTE: This should be cross browser compatible, and will also likely be faster than any JQuery alternative.

Comment: This is buggy when refreshing browser. Need to refresh twice to get updated true index

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = [your array];
var i = 0;

$.each(myArray, function(){
    if (this.id === 'bb') return false;
    i++;
})

console.log(i) // will log '1'
```

---

Update with modern JS.

```
let index
myArray.map(function(item, i){
    if (item.id === 'cc') index = i
})

console.log(index) // will log '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

inArray can't work with multidimensional array so try like the following

```
var globalarray= [
            {"id" : "aa", "description" : "some description1"},
            {"id" : "bb", "description" : "some more description"},
            {"id" : "cc", "description" : "a lot of description"}];
var theIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < globalarray.length; i++) {
    if (globalarray[i].id == 'bb') {
        theIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
alert(theIndex);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu2Bt/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.each - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
var i;
jQuery.each(array, function(index, value){
   if(value.id == 'bb'){
      i = index;
      return false; // retrun false to stop the loops
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(yourObject).indexOf(yourValue);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation so the OP understands why this code solves his problem.