# Get array index number based on array element id

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects, each object, a div, has an `id`.
Can I retrieve the array index number of a given object based on its `id` using this?

```
var index = ar.map(function(el) {
  return el. ??
}).indexOf('objectID4');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19111224/1636522

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var index = ar.map(function(el) {
  return el.id;
}).indexOf('objectID4');
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bvT6B/

Comment: I tried that, I'm getting -1. and I know that objectID4 exists for sure

Comment: @user3024007 May be case sensitivity kicks in

Comment: yes, I see...  I have to figure out why my live code is not taking it

Answer (score 0):

check for below code

```
var ar = [{'id':'objectId1','foo':'bar'},{'id':'objectId4','foo':'bar'}]

var index = ar.map(function(el) {
   return el.id;
}).indexOf('objectId4');

alert(index);
```

Or you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/VJrWc/

If this is not you want the share some more code and clear your goal.

Answer (score -1):

It this what you want?

```
<div id="x1" class='foo'></div>
<div id="x2" class='foo'></div>
<div id="x3" class='foo'></div>

<div id="res"></div>
<script>
function getIndexOfById(uid) {
    var id = null;
    $('.foo').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == uid) {id = $(this).index();}
    });
    return id;
}

$('#res').html(getIndexOfById('x1') + ' / ' + getIndexOfById('x2') + ' / ' + getIndexOfById('x3'));
</script>
```

The result is

```
0 / 1 / 2
```

Comment: `$('#x1').index('.foo')`!!!