# get index of object in array in object in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, impactjs

working with Impactjs, a game engine, here and levels have this very strange setup:

```
[
    {
       "entities": [
            {"type":"type1","x":100,"y":100,"settings":{"directsTo":"-5"}},
            {"type":"type2","x":101,"y":101,"settings":{"directsTo":"-4"}}
        ],
        "layer": [
            other data
         ]
    }
]
```

I'm wondering how one gets the index of the type1 object based off of the directsTo property of the settings object?

Javascript or jQuery would be fine.

Edit:
The game has to work on smoothly on mobile so having an efficient solution is good.

Comment: A simple forloop can do that. However,for repetitive complex calculations like this,I would suggest you to include underscore.js in your stack. http://underscorejs.org/#where

Comment: would a for loop be faster than some jQuery or javascript function?  Working with mobile and we already have performance issues.

Comment: There is no common functions for get index of object. But you can get create your own function for get index. As example, same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111224/get-index-of-array-of-objects-via-jquery

Comment: @dlkulp I meant a function having a forloop to identify the object and return the index number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var arr =[{
    "entities": [{
        "type": "type1",
        "x": 100,"y": 100,
        "settings": {"directsTo": "-5"}
    }, {
        "type": "type2",
        "x": 101,"y": 101,
        "settings": {"directsTo": "-4"}
    }],
    "layer": ['other data']
}];
var t='type1';
var newArr=arr[0];
for(var data in newArr){
    for(a in newArr[data]){
        if(newArr[data][a].type == t){
             alert('Index of '+t+' is '+a+' in '+data);
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5hMC2/)

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5hMC2/1/)

Comment: close, doesn't get the id of the containing object with the correct property from the settings object

Comment: Here `directsTo` is your `id`, -5 in the above case? See my updated demo once.

Comment: again, closer, the problem is that I don't care about type at all, I just need the index of the object with the directsTo value that I'm searching with.

Comment: yup, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `filter` property?

Assuming your JS object looks like this

```
var j = [
    {
       "entities": [
            {"type":"type1","x":100,"y":100,"settings":{"directsTo":"-5"}},
            {"type":"type2","x":101,"y":101,"settings":{"directsTo":"-4"}}
        ],
        "layer": [
            "otherdata":{}
         ]
    }
];
```

You can find the object using

```
var result = j[0].entities.filter(function(n) { return n.settings.directsTo == "-5"; });
// result[0].type == "type1"
```

Comment: I'm not concerned with the rest of the object, I just need the index of the object in the entities array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which gets the index of an object among other objects, for example like this

```
//assuming you have the data parsed as a JSON object "data"
//and you also have your entity object as "obj"
function getIndex(obj, data){
    return data.entities.indexOf(obj);
}
```

if you don't have the "obj" object you will have to create a function which first finds the correct object based on an attribute, for example the type parameter

```
function findEntity(type, source){
    for(var i=0; i<source.entities.length; i++){
        if(source.entities[i].type == type){
            return source.entities[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

now you can call it like this

```
getIndex(findEntity("type1", data), data);
```

Hope it helps you start off!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Rohan Kumar and  Виктор Новиков.

```
var array =[
    {
        "entities": [
            {
                "type": "type1",
                "x": 100,"y": 100,
                "settings": {"directsTo": "-5"}
            },
            {
                "type": "type2",
                "x": 101,"y": 101,
                "settings": {"directsTo": "-4"}
            }
        ],
        "layer": ['other data']
    }
];

function getArrayIndexForLocationKey(arr, val) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].settings.directsTo == val)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[live here](http://jsfiddle.net/tL4AE/)